# Subtitle Workshop and Pascal: divide subtitles intelligently

Tags: word-wrap, pascalscript

Is there any Pascal script good to make Subtitle Workshop to split lines "intelligently" from the point of view of the type of the word?

The idea is rather simple, and it is exactly the standards that professional subtitlers use for subtitles to be accepted for commercial use:

To be considered professional, subtitles not only need to follow certain timing and length rules, but also have correct word splits at certain words and places. From a professional point of view, subtitles are not allowed to end like this at the end of each line:

I am going to the
beach because today is a

very nice day and the
sun is up shinning on

........................of
........................for

I start from a .txt file, which is not optimized. And all those words at the end of the 1st line must be sent to the beginning of the 2nd line. Hopefully, a Pascal script could do that once you define which are the words that should be sent to the 2nd line, if they are at the end of the 1st line.

You will not see any TV series with subtitles ending in the forbidden words as it´s not professional. I really need to solve this. So, any tips you can give me are hugely welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, but what have you tried so far? :)

Answer (score 0):

Subtitle editing requires a not so very common complex algorithm.

Without additionnal input (your Pascal script first try) to your question, I am afraid the only best place where you can get valuable answer is at the URUWorks's [forum](http://www.urusoft.net/forum/index.php).

**Edit:**

Apart from scripting consideration, it may take some additional knowledge to program such as [hyphenation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lout_%28software%29) in a given language.

Judge by yourself, the hyphenation rule used by the [Lout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lout_%28software%29) Document Formatting Language for the french language has more than 1000 lines of code.

**Edit2:**

You can find [here](http://synopse.info/files/hyphen.zip) an opensource Hyphenation Delphi unit (english, french, italian and spanish hyphen tables included ).